# In TCP, if the server uses another port to communicate, how will it inform the client?

Tags: sockets, tcp

I'm studying socket programming in C. In TCP communication, a classical situation is that once the server accept() a connect() request from a client, it will fork a new process to handle this communication. Then the child process will use another port to communicate with the client. My question is, how does the server inform the client that it will use another port rather than the original one to do the subsequent communication? Which field in the TCP header and which phase of the handshake can reflect the port change?

For example, process PA on server A is listening to its port 80. Now process PB on client B wants to connect to A's port 80. Once PA accepts PB's connecting request, it will fork a new process PA1 to handle the communication with PB. Am I right till now? Next, will PA1 still use port 80 or another port such as 1234 to communication with PB? If it still uses 80, how can the server A distribute PB's communication to PA1? If it uses another port like 1234, how will the server A inform PB to use 1234 for the subsequent communication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A TCP connection is uniquely identified by the tuple (source ip, source port, destination ip, destinatin port). These tuple is used by OS to "bind" the TCP connection to a process, meaning to know which process the OS should deliver the TCP package to.

When server socket accepts the TCP connection and fork, that process inherits the original process so it effectively take up the binding of the TCP connection to this newly forked process. The client in the remote machine does not know and does not need to know such thing happens. The whole network keeps seeing the same thing, the package of the same tuple flow through the network.

At this time, the original process will keep listening to new TCP connection. When new TCP connection request arrive, even it is from the same previous machine, the port must be different. In OS's perspective it is a different tuple, therefore it can distinguish the TCP pcakge and deliver to the right process.

You may ask why the client from the remote machine knows it has to use another port to initiate a new connection. This is simply because the client OS knows (or informed by the socket library) that this process is creating a separate new connection. OS will assign another unique port number to the process. That's how it is possible for multiple processes communicating to the same server port without message mess up.

To put it short, the operation of accept and fork in server is just a kind of transferring the ownership of a TCP connection binding to another process. Nothing change in the server port used in this communication.

Comment: Your answer really makes sense. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The port number only needs to be different if it's another connection from the same client host.

Comment: Exactly. The important thing to note is that the server **does not** change port numbers after calling accept. A webserver, for instance, will continue to use port 80 for the port number on its side of the socket. Only the client-side port number will be different.

Answer (score 1):

> In TCP communication, a classical situation is that once the server accept() a connect() request from a client, it will fork a new process to handle this communication.

Correct, or start a thread.

> Then the child process will use another port to communicate with the client.

No. It will use the same port, via the accepted socket, inherited in the case of a child process.

> My question is, how does the server inform the client that it will use another port rather than the original one to do the subsequent communication?

It doesn't, because this isn't the 'classical situation'.

> Which field in the TCP header and which phase of the handshake can reflect the port change?

None. It doesn't happen that way. It would be a waste of a port.

> For example, process PA on server A is listening to its port 80. Now process PB on client B wants to connect to A's port 80. Once PA accepts PB's connecting request, it will fork a new process PA1 to handle the communication with PB. Am I right till now?

Yes.

> Next, will PA1 still use port 80 or another port such as 1234 to communication with PB?

Port 80.

> If it still uses 80, how can the server A distribute PB's communication to PA1?

By inheritance of the accepted socket.

> If it uses another port like 1234, how will the server A inform PB to use 1234 for the subsequent communication?

Doesn't happen.

Comment: If the ports were the same, how would the server know which packet went with which connection?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The connection is identified by the tuple {source IP, source port, target IP, target port}. This is TCP/IP 101. Are you suggesting that the server-side ports are different for listening and accepted sockets? Or just asking a rhetorical question?

Comment: I'm pointing out that you didn't answer the question. "*If it still uses 80, how can the server A distribute PB's communication to PA1? If it uses another port like 1234, how will the server A inform PB to use 1234 for the subsequent communication?*" The answer is that it uses both ports.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz No, the answer is that it doesn't have to do anything. The connection is already established: all the server has to do is fork the child process and let it inherit the socket. *Of course* the connection uses the local and remote ports, but that isn't the answer to the question. The question is about a fictitious new server-side port, and the answer is to say so, and to name the actual mechanism, which is that the child process inherits the accepted socket. Which I did.

Comment: The "fictitious new server-side port" is the actual client side port.

Comment: Maybe I didn't make my question clear. It's my bad. If two processes PB1 and PB2 on client B want to connect to server A's port 80, PB1 and PB2 will use two different ports on client B, like 5001 and 5002. I guess that's what @DavidSchwartz said. Right? What I want to make clear is: if process PC on client C and process PD on client D want to communicate with Server A's 80 port, server A will create two child processes (PAC and PAD) to separately communicate with PC and PD. I'm right till now.

Comment: (cont'd) Question is: will PAC and PAD still use 80 on server A to communicate with PC and PD, or use other ports on server A? @EJP said they will still use 80. How do you think about this answer, @DavidSchwartz?

Comment: @MatthewMa I think his answer doesn't answer the question at all. It completely fails to explain how the connections are distinguished or what the role of the two port numbers are.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz After carefully reading your answers, I think you two both answered my question. EJP said the server still uses 80(that's part of my question), while you made it clear how does the server distinguishes the clients. I think I have gotten the final answer. Thank you all:)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The question clearly states 'The child process will *then* [my emphasis] use another port to communicate with the client'. This is what the question is about, and it isn't true. No new port is introduced and the child process stage. Your question above about 'if the ports were the same' only adds to the confusion. They *are* the same as used in the original communication between client and parent server process.

Comment: That is true. The client will use another port, that is, not just the server listening port. You're finding a pedantic excuse to ignore the substance of the question.

Comment: I have answered the question, all six of them, in detail. You've answered what is basically a different question by citing an action that had already taken place before anything in this question occurred.

Answer (score -1):

The client chooses this port, not the server. The client will choose a port that's not already in use on that particular machine, and use that port to tell its connections apart (just as the server does).

For example say the client has IP address 1.2.3.4 and the server has IP address 4.3.2.1 and listens on port 80. If the client has two connections to that server and port, how will it tell them apart? Simple -- it assigns a different source port to each one. Say one gets port 50001 and one gets port 50002, then the two connections are:

1.2.3.4:50001 -> 4.3.2.1:80
and
1.2.3.4:50002 -> 4.3.2.1:80

The server knows these ports because it gets them from the TCP SYN packets sent from the client to the server. So the client tells the server, not the other way around.

Comment: I'm confused. Let me try to make it clear. Process PA on server A is listening to its port 80. Now process PB on client B wants to connect to A's port 80. Once PA accepts PB's connecting request, it will fork a new process PA1 to handle the communication with PB. Am I right till now? Next, will PA1 still use port 80 or another port such as 1234 to communication with PB? If it still uses 80, how can the server A distribute PB's communication to PA1? If it uses another port like 1234, how will the server A inform PB to use 1234 for the subsequent communication?

Comment: The destination port will be 80. The source port will be whatever the client chose. (Read my answer again.)

Comment: The client chooses or rather is usually allocated his own local port. Not the 'this port' described in the question, which is a totally fictitious new server-side port. Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @EJP Did you not read the question?! "*If it still uses 80, how can the server A distribute PB's communication to PA1?*" The answer is, that it also uses another port, chosen by the client.

Comment: It uses a connection which has already been established between its own listening port and the client-side port which had already been chosen by the client before the first SYN was sent. Not a new port of any description.

Comment: @EJP Right, that's what I explained in my answer! That is, I actually answered the question asked.

Comment: There are six questions asked, and all but the one you answered revolve around the fictitious new port.

Comment: Right, but the point is that there is a second port, and it used for precisely the thing he's asking about -- distinguishing the two connections.